Find index in map object using JavaScript
If we want to find index in array of objects, it's pretty simple. Example below
let a = [
  {prop1:"abc",prop2:"qwe"},
  {prop1:"bnmb",prop2:"yutu"},
  {prop1:"zxvz",prop2:"qwrq"}];
    
let index = a.findIndex(x => x.prop2 ==="yutu");

console.log(index);

I have a map object as shown below
let input = new Map([
    [ 
      "gfg4343434333r",
      { "group": 1, "groupId": "ae027a9e56a2" }
    ],
    [ 
       "5ae027a9e56a2",
        { "group": 2, "groupId": "434346456454" }
    ],
    [ 
        "de027a9e56a2",
        { "group": 3, "groupId": "43343vvfbrrt4445" }
    ],
])

As you can see this map object has a key value pair. suppose I have a input2 as 5ae027a9e56a2 I need to find out which key matches with this input2 and get its position in input. In this case 5ae027a9e56a2 matches with the 2nd element. Once it matches, I want to know the index so that I can go one level above and gets its previous element value.
How do I find the index in map object and how to get to index-1 in such cases? Can someone please shed some light here.?

I don't think a Map has a concept of an index

@JaromandaX - is there any way i can get this without trying to find index then ?

Can you convert it to an array and use findIndex()?

if the ordinal position of the elements of the Map remain fixed, I guess you could use [...input.keys()].findIndex

You can use Array.from(map) to convert your map into an array of arrays where the first item in the inner arrays is the ID you want to find its index, then apply findIndex. This doesn't seem like an ideal solution, so let me ask: why you want the index?

then how do i go to (index-1) in the map object ? @codejockie

A map doesn't have the concept of index but does a key. In your case, the key is the ID you want so simply doing map[key] will get you the value associated with that key. If you want all the keys as an array, use map.keys(), for all values, use map.values(). You do not need an index but a key.

map[key] will get value associated with that key. agreed. how do i get map[key-1] i.e previous entry in this map object above @codejockie

@ArenTrot you will need to convert to array and findIndex. then using that index you can find the previous key, then the previous key can be applied to access the value from the map const entries = Array.from(input); const index = entries.findIndex(e => e[0] === "5ae027a9e56a2" ); console.log(entries[index-1][1]);

Although maps preserve insertion order, why are you using a map in the first place if you need to access elements by index? That's what arrays are for.

If you are dealing with "raw" input such as JSON data, it should not be in a Map.
You can build a "key" to index lookup Map on the side that can be used to speed up index checking.


const input = [
  ["gfg4343434333r", {
    "group": 1,
    "groupId": "ae027a9e56a2"
  }],
  ["5ae027a9e56a2", {
    "group": 2,
    "groupId": "434346456454"
  }],
  ["de027a9e56a2", {
    "group": 3,
    "groupId": "43343vvfbrrt4445"
  }],
]

// Build a lookup map of "key" to index
const keyToIndex = input.reduce((m, [k], i) => m.set(k, i), new Map)

console.log(getPreviousIndex('gfg4343434333r')) // -1
console.log(getPreviousIndex('5ae027a9e56a2'))  //  0
console.log(getPreviousIndex('de027a9e56a2'))   //  1

function getPreviousIndex(key) {
  let previousIndex = keyToIndex.get(key) - 1
  return previousIndex >= 0 ? previousIndex : -1
}



